# How to turn off folding of final variables in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class R {
private R(){}

public static abstract class Resources {
    private Resources() {
    }

    public static final String
    STR1 = "Foo",
    STR2 = "Foo";
    }
}
```

And it turns out, that Eclipse collapses the "public static final String" part, when I press "Collapse all" shortcut. And the trick is that there's no "plus" sign at the left of this collapsed code. So I can suggest that this code is present only by looking at the lines' indexes to the left. But I still can't expand this code manually. Here's how it looks like:
[image: Screenshot]
The collapsed code is on lines 21-23, and, obviously, not visible. So, any suggestions of how can I either expand it (and only in, nothing else), or prohibit eclipse from collapsing static final fields?

Comment: It's not happening on my Eclipse.

Comment: Which Eclipse version is this?

Comment: My version is: Juno Service Release 1

Comment: Actually, I can expand everything using "Ctrl-Shift-*". I want to expand only this particular tricky fold.

Comment: I am using `Indigo`, same in my eclipse too.

Comment: Well just use `public static final String STR1 = "Foo", STR2 = "FOO";` instead?

Comment: I often have much more static vars to include, so this will not always help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what's happening is that because the two variable declarations use the same tokens for attributes the AST parser is building a block out of the declaration even though from a syntax perspective there is no block.  The only workaround I can suggest is to split the statement into two separate declarations.